# Problem while debugging React application in Chrome browser locally. Transpiled variable with `_myVar` has value where as `myVar` does not have it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, debugging, webpack

I am using webpack 3 to compile my react application. When I try to debug code locally in browser (source tab in Dev Tools) for some strange reason I see few variables has `undefined' where as others has correct value.

When I expanded scope section I can see variable has equivalent transpiled name simiar to `_variableName` which has got value where as against normal variable name `variableName` value is `undefined`